# How to parse date from yahoo's weather API to Java Date

Tags: android, api, yahoo, weather

I'm using Yahoo weather API to build some simple app. In the JSON receiver there is `pubDate` field which is (according to the documentation) in [RFC 882](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc882) (it looks like `"pubDate":1546992000`). Does anyone know how to convert such date to date in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this : 
`new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date( [yourDateValue] * 1000L))`
You can test the result here : https://www.unixtimeconverter.io/ [Insert your pubDate here]

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: This Answer ignores crucial issue of time zones.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(yourDateValue)));
```

You can check and convert miliseconds to date from [here](https://currentmillis.com/). When I write your reference value for convert, it gives me a date from 1970. You must add "000" to end of your value or multiply by 1000 for getting correct date.

Comment: These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochSecond( 
    Long.parseLong( "1546992000" ) 
)
```

…represents the first moment of January 1, 2019 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

> 2019-01-09T00:00:00Z

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible `Date`/`Calendar`/`SimpleDateFormat` classes.

Assuming that `1546992000` represents a number of whole seconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, parse as an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1_546_992_000L );
```

> instant.toString(): 2019-01-09T00:00:00Z

To see that moment through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), adjust to a `ZonedDateTime` instance.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

> ZonedDateTime.toString(): 2019-01-09T01:00+01:00[Africa/Casablanca]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).